# How to model MPPT technique with PID controller

Tags: matlab, pid-controller, solar-energy, simulink, mppt

I need to model a MPPT algorithm with a PID controller at Simulink. The model will feed the gates of two mosfets of a push-pull converter.

I have to extract max power from PV and have a fixed voltage(400V) at the output of push-pull converter even the irradiation decreases. I probably use incremental conductance or P&O algorithm for MPPT but i haven't decided yet.

I have read some papers about this and acording to them, i need to measure Vpv and Ipv from panel and put them into a "something"(matlab fuction, or a different type algorithm) then output of this "something" will be referance voltage and finally give this referance and feedback from converter output into a PID controller and produce a duty cycle for mosfets.

I understand the concept but i don't know how to write the code or model the algorithm which transform the Vpv and Ipv into referance voltage.( i mean the relationship for this change, because the panel output will be like 35 V and the output voltage should be 400V)
Also i want to ask what load should i use for having fixed voltage at the output of converter? (I may model the load as if it is DC bus with constant voltage and according to power the output current varies but again i could not figure out how to do)

I am using this as my final project at university and so far couldn't get help about it so i will be appreciate any help.

Comment: Will you cite us in the report afterwards?

Comment: [Very similar to your earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386827/how-to-model-a-load-with-constant-voltage-in-simulink) except now you are considering that MPPT **is** your problem.

Comment: @HarrySvensson yes of course this is a ofiicial thesis and it will be done according to rules.

Comment: @Andyaka hahahah, my earlier concern is still alive , i am changing resistor value which is necessary for getting desired voltage value at the same time changing the irradiation. This is not my real need but for now it should be enough the practise MPPT algorithm

Comment: Do you understand this: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Susovon_Samanta2/publication/276404676/figure/fig4/AS:383704674390016@1468493731259/Flowchart-of-the-conventional-P-O-MPPT-algorithm.png

Comment: yes?? But i will use a PID controller after MPPT algorithm

Comment: How can i have the required Duty Cycle value by using a MPPT system and PID controller for getting max power from panel and 400 V output at the DC-DC converter?                                     
Panel voltage at MPP =36 V and current = 8.61 A

Comment: The power characteristics of renewable like solar panel change a lot during the day therefore it is a highly non-linear system which PID is not well suited for this  application...

Comment: As a load i used  Wye-Connected Variable Load" block as load to my system . It is for 3 phase but i connect the "+" terminal to the "a" input and "-" to the "n" input so it worked for DC system. The block changes the resistor according to external P(power) input and internal Rated Voltage parameter. May be it helps someone having similar problem

Comment: What part are you trying to control? Keeping the solar panel operating at MPP? Or the DC bus at 400VDC? If you are trying to do both, you have to adjust the current draw of the load such that the MPPT operates in a way that the dcdc convertor maintains a DC bus voltage of 400VDC which seems like a weird scheme. Normally, you want MPPT for charging batteries at max current to extract the most available energy. Or, you regulate the voltage or current to the load and relax the MPPT operating point requirement. Doing both seems unusual. What is your "variable load"?

Answer (score 1):

I am also doing a project like yours. And I am having the same problem as you. Btw i have progressed a little bit. You can use simulinks function block to write the code. You shall find it under used defined function block. You also have to use memory block so that previous samples data is available to you. You can use delay too. But then you have to specify sampling frequency. First with the use of zero order hold block take sample of current and voltage- feed them to memory block,then calculate dv,di ,feed them to simulink used defined function ,add the PID to the output of function. One thing though, for PID tuning you may need state space model of your converter.